# Vim function to sort by lines by tags

Tags: vim

I'm trying to create a custom function in gVim to sort lines based on a tag and I'm a bit out of my depth. The goal is for me to create a custom function in my _gvimrc so I can resort like this quickly and as necessary. I need some pointers as to where to study.

My goal is to group lines by a tag at the start of the line

```
file contents 1
:a some text
:b some other text
:a more text
:b more other text
:c final text
file contents 2
```

will become

```
:a
some text
more text
:b
some other text
more other text
:c
final text

file contents 1
file contents 2
```

The challenge is largely that I don't want to mess with the other lines in the file - those which have no tags. the :sort function will reorder all of those.

I have a feeling I will need to:
1. yank all the lines with tags into a register, and delete them (some kind of :g/pattern/yank register ?)
2. put them all at the beginning of the file (some kind of :g/pattern/put register ?)
3. sort the block by the tags (some kind of :sort r /pattern/ ?)
4. iterate over each tag to reformat from

```
:a text
:a text
:a text
```

to

```
:a
text
text
text
```

I'm not proficient enough in gVim to know where to really start - if anyone here is expert enough to assist with one of these sub-problems, so to speak, or has a better idea for the methodology, I'd really appreciate it. I'm particularly stymied on number 4.

If this isn't the kind of thing gVim is capable of, please let me know, but I have a feeling this is quite possible and just out of my pay grade.

Comment: Your first step is actually rather easy, as it's simply `:%sort /^:/ | 1,/^:/-m$`. Can't think of an easy way to get rid of the extra `:a`/`:b`/.... though....

Comment: The thing is, won't that sort command also sort all of the other lines in the document? I need those to remain in the order they were in. Essentially I need to sort only the tagged lines.

Comment: no, you can see from `:help :sort`: `If a {pattern} is used, any lines which don't have a match for {pattern} are kept in their current order, (…)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think awk or some higher language would fit this better. Example using `awk` and Vim's filter, `%!`:

```
:%!awk '$1 ~ /^:/ { a[$1] = a[$1] substr($0, 3) "\n"; next} {r = r $0 "\n"} END { asorti(a, keys); for (k in keys) { print keys[k]; print a[keys[k]] } print ""; print r}'
```

Prettier version:

```
$1 ~ /^:/ {
    a[$1] = a[$1] substr($0, 3) "\n";
    next
}

{
    r = r $0 "\n"
}

END {
    asorti(a, keys);
    for (k in keys) {
        print keys[k];
        print a[keys[k]]
    }
    print "";
    print r
}
```

Note: I use `gawk`

Comment: I appreciate the example but I'm not really prepared to learn a new language specifically to solve this problem. I'm not even a programmer by trade.